# Is there a way to select the second occurence of a classname when its not a direct sibiling in CSS/SCSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'd like target the second instance of a class without adding another class. `:nth-child` and `:nth-of-type` doesnt seem to work because its not sibling. Is this possible?

```
<div>
  <div>First class.
    <p className="blue">1st paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div> hello
    <section>
       <p class="blue">2nd paragraph.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe its possible with _just_ CSS... what's your use case for targeting on the second one? Could you expand upon what you're trying to do once you select it?

Comment: Can't you do `div > div + div > section > p.blue`?

Comment: there's no chance in css because you can't select the second occurence of a class in the document. There's no operator and no trick like that. But you can find strategies to circumvent its lack. Like just going on the second occurence of results given by `querySelector()` or making your rule more specific (but violating the expected semantic of wanting to select the i-th occurence of a class or any given other selector). It's very painful when I'm not using jQuery that instead does have the `:eq(i)` selector. I often miss that. Because you have to break the chain and run querySelector again.

Comment: And found out only now that it's in the works! Maybe: https://css-tricks.com/css-nth-of-class-selector/

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Interesting link, thanks for that. But it won't solve the OP's issue because the `<p>`'s are not siblings.
@SaaShaPina To answer your question: no, this is not possible. You can either use the fact that the target is in a `<section>` with `section .blue {...}` or you can add css classes to your markup to support your styling needs like `<p class="blue highlight">` and `.blue.highlight {...}`

Answer (score 0):

The chosen nested markup prevents any form of targeting child-indexed pseudo-classes, now and in future. But, as of now, there is a chance with markup which can be targeted by the [`:nth-child(An+B [of S]?)`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo) form of an additional tree-structural child-indexed pseudo-class selector of the [*Selectors Level 4*](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/) draft/specification.

```css
body { margin: 0; font-size: .95em; }
div, p { margin: 3px; font-size: inherit; }

.blue { color: lightblue; }
.orange { color: orange; }
.red { color: palevioletred; }

:nth-child(2 of .blue) { color: palevioletred; }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    hello
    <p class="blue">
      1st paragraph and 1st of ".blue"
    </p>
    <p class="orange">
      2nd paragraph and 1st of ".orange"
    </p>
    <p class="blue">
      3rd paragraph and 2nd of ".blue"
      <br/>
      (... as of now will be
      <span class="red">red in safari</span>
      since it already supports the
      <a class="red" href="https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo">
        <code>:nth-child(An+B [of S]?)</code>
      </a>
      tree-structural child-indexed pseudo-class selector of the
      <a class="red" href="https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/">
        Selectors Level 4
      </a>
      specification ...)
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    hello
    <p class="blue">
      1st paragraph and 1st of ".blue"
    </p>
    <section>
      <p class="blue">
        1st paragraph and 1st of ".blue"
      </p>
    </section>
    <p class="blue">
      2nd paragraph and 2nd of ".blue"
      (should be <span class="red">red in safari</span>)
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SaaShaPina ... Regarding the above provided answer are there any questions left?