# How to apply different color on each logo

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-variables

[image]

I tried similar way on any other tags, and it worked. So I tried it again for this. but it didn't work. Is there any thing I missed?? I'd appreciate if you let me know about any solution or advice.

```css
.menual__img-logo i {
  color: var(--color__pink);
}

.menual__img-logo i:nth-child(2) {
  color: var(--color__light-blue);
}

.menual__img-logo i:nth-child(3) {
  color: var(--color__light-orange);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="menual__img-logo ">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-lightbulb"></i>
</div>
<div class="menual__img-logo ">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
</div>
<div class="menual__img-logo ">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It does not look much like your image - please update with the vars you use

Comment: _"Is there any thing I missed?"_ - yes, what "child" actually means. _All_ of your `i` elements are the first, and last, and one and only child of their respective parents divs. You need to apply this on the level of those divs, `.menual__img-logo:nth-child(2) i` - but that will of course only work if those divs are the first elements within _their_ parent element, if not, then you'd need a different number in the selector.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have single element inside `.menual__img-logo`, that's why `:nth-child` on `i` does not work (`i` is always first/last child). Move `:nth-child` from `i` to `.menual__img-logo`

```css
.menual__img-logo i {
  color: pink;
}

.menual__img-logo:nth-child(2) i {
  color: blue;
}

.menual__img-logo:nth-child(3) i {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div>
  <div class="menual__img-logo ">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-lightbulb"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="menual__img-logo ">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="menual__img-logo ">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the provided code correctly rendered, the OP needs to ...

1. declare the custom color properties.
2. change the markup to a more robust variant where one can precisely target each child element.
3. apply the correct css rules which target each child element.

```css
:root {
  --color__pink: #facfcf;
  --color__light-blue: #95cbca;
  --color__light-orange: #ffbf8b;
}
/* defaults */
.logos i,
.menual__img-logo i {
  color: var(--color__pink);
}
/*
  (direct) child elements of the
  '.logos' classified parent node.
*/
.logos i:nth-child(2) {
  color: var(--color__light-blue);
}
.logos i:nth-child(3) {
  color: var(--color__light-orange);
}
/*
  (nested) child elements of 
  an unidentified parent node.
*/
.menual__img-logo:nth-child(2) i {
  color: var(--color__light-blue);
}
.menual__img-logo:nth-child(3) i {
  color: var(--color__light-orange);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="logos">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-lightbulb"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="menual__img-logo">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-lightbulb"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="menual__img-logo">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="menual__img-logo">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is another solution though which allows the OP to stay with the original markup.

The [Selectors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/) draft/specification introduces child selectors of the [`:nth-child(An+B [of S]?)`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo) form of an additional tree-structural child-indexed pseudo-class selector.

E.g. See another example at SO ... [*"Is there a way to select the second occurence of a classname when its not a direct sibiling in CSS/SCSS?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71945806/is-there-a-way-to-select-the-second-occurence-of-a-classname-when-its-not-a-dire)

*+ + +*

***Note***

*The next provided solution, **as of today**, is supported by up to date **Safari** browsers **only**.*

```css
:root {
  --color__pink: #facfcf;
  --color__light-blue: #95cbca;
  --color__light-orange: #ffbf8b;
}
.menual__img-logo i {
  color: var(--color__pink);
}
.menual__img-logo:nth-child(2 of .menual__img-logo) i {
  color: var(--color__light-blue);
}
.menual__img-logo:nth-child(3 of .menual__img-logo) i {
  color: var(--color__light-orange);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="menual__img-logo ">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-lightbulb"></i>
</div>

<p>just a random child in beetween</p>

<div class="menual__img-logo ">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
</div>

<p>another child for demonstration purposes</p>

<div class="menual__img-logo ">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i>
</div>
```